# C# Dapper QueryAsync to ValueTuple not mapping correctly

Tags: c#, dapper, c#-7.0

I'm doing the following query using dapper and C#7 ValueTuples (installed nuget):

```
await connection.QueryAsync<(int, Guid)>(
                $@"SELECT tenant, pid FROM Table 
                ORDER BY id
                OFFSET {skip} ROWS 
                FETCH NEXT {dbBatchSize} ROWS ONLY");
```

It returns a list of 0 and Guid.Empty.

If I use only int or only Guid it works ok

I also tried naming the ValueTuple according to the columns in the table:

```
await connection.QueryAsync<(int tenant, Guid pid)>("...")
```

Same result.

Anyone has any tip?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a side note, have you ever wondered what will happen to all that interpolation and concatenation? The compiler is cleaver enough to ignore interpolated strings without holes and has long concatenated constant strings at compile-time. So that will be o constant string and two interpolated strings (`string.Fornat`) when what you need is one string, or, if Dapper supports it, a `FormattableString`. Have a look at [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string).

Comment: Oh yeah, it is actually missing a @ on the question :p Thanks,  I will update it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known limitation of dapper. It doesn't support copying a query result into a ValueTuple. [There is an open issue on Github requesting support for this](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/735).

The OP of that request creating a working example of how it could be done in April and it is currently scheduled for the v2.0 release.

Answer (score 6):

Dapper seems to support ValueTuple query mappings since v.1.50.4, although the issue [David Arno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7122/david-arno) pointed out is still open. We've been utilizing this feature for a while in our projects.

I'm unable to find any mentions of added support in release notes either, but I managed to find an [example usage](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/80231b4d2b2391bbb01c2cd7be75fbecfe0c0296/Dapper.Tests/TupleTests.cs#L22) of this feature in Dapper's test project.